# DNS failure in firefox

Tags: firefox

I am trying to access intranet web application from firefox. I am getting `DNS Failure notification.`

But I am able to open the same page successfully in Chrome and IE.

Can some one tell the solution to the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Restart Firefox? Try Ctrl+F5? It should use the host DNS resolving .. or is there a proxy/DNS configuration?

Comment: @user2246674. Just changed the proxy settings to Auto detect.Then it worked. Thank you.

Comment: @Patan I was having same issue in firefox version 94 (Latest 2021). It was resolved with your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just changed the Proxy setting to Auto Detect. Hence it worked